# How to make the predicate spent(Passengers, Year, Sum) in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need to write a predicate "spent" that would find the total costs for tickets of passengers from
of the "Passengers" list in the given year "Year".

I have these facts:

```
trip(01, Tokio, Toronto, 1500).        /trip   (Id, From, To, Price)/
trip(02, California, London, 700).       

ticket(01, Sara, 2021-12-26).          /ticket (Id, Passenger, Date)/
ticket(02, Jane, 2021-05-21).
```

I wrote this code, but it is not enough to complete the task, please help.

```
sum_cash(Price) :- spent(sum(A), trip(_, _, _, A), Price).
```

Comment: Could use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=aggregate_all/3 - examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=prolog+aggregate_all

Comment: None of the code you show works for me. The first code snippet has compiler errors and the query tells me that "spent" is not defined. If you clean up the code you have shared maybe we have a firm ground to stand on.